# How can i modify the php code to recieve 5 numbers without duplicates/repeating numbers?

Tags: php, random, numbers

i have this php code:

```
<?php
function GetRand($N, $min=1, $max=59) {
$Local = array();
mt_srand(time());
for ($i=0;$i<$N;$i++) 
$LocalArr [] = mt_rand($min, $max); 
return $LocalArr;
}
$A = GetRand(5);
foreach($A as $K=>$v) echo "$v ";
?>
```

The result is 5 numbers between 1 and 59. The problem is that sometimes i receive results like this:

43  9  13  9  7
In those 5 numbers, there is the number 9 twice. I would like to change the php code, so everytime when there is a number that repeats, this number should be skipped and instead of the repeated number should be represented another number, so that every time i have 5 numbers and no duplicates between them.

Thank you very much in Advance!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = range(1, 59);
shuffle($numbers);
var_dump(array_slice($numbers, 0, 5));
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, but i am totaly new to php. can you please write down the whole php code, because i am not sure where to your code into my php code. Thank you very much in Advance!

Comment: That *is* the whole code. Replace your entire code with the above. But instead of just var-dumping the array, assign it to a variable in the end (e.g. `$A = array_slice($numbers, 0, 5);`).

Comment: Study the code and try to understand it. It's three simple steps: 1) Create an array filled with numbers 1 through 59. 2) Shuffle the array. 3) Take the first 5 entries from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
<?php

    $randoms = array(rand(1,59));
    while(sizeof($randoms) <= 5) {

        $randoms[] = rand(1,59);
        $randoms = array_unique($randoms);

    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, but i am totaly new to php. can you please write down the whole php code, because i am not sure where to your code into my php code. Thank you very much in Advance!

Comment: This is the whole PHP-code. It returns an array with 5 different numbers in it, you can see it doing var_dump($randoms); Anyway, the answer of @deceze is better, you should use that one. :)